# MySQL query to order alphabetically A-Z but "AA" after "Z"

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have data in a MySQL table, with `title` like so:

```
16A Activated Charcoal
16AA Lidocaine Viscous Gel (Xylocaine ®)
16B Adenosine ( Adenocard)
16BB Lorazepam (Ativan)
16C Albuterol (Proventil, Ventolin)
16CC Magnesium Sulfate
16D Amidarone Cordarone, Nexterone
16E Aspirin
16F  Atropine Sulfate
16G Calcium Chloride
[...]
16Z DuoDote Auto-Injector
```

My app uses this SQL query to build a list of the data:

```
SELECT uid, file, title 
FROM library 
WHERE section = '$uid' AND enabled >0 
ORDER BY title ASC
```

This works, except that MySQL (correctly) puts 16AA immediately following 16A (as listed above). What I want is to list all 16A-16Z, followed by 16AA-16ZZ. Thus returning data in this order:

```
16A Activated Charcoal
16B Adenosine ( Adenocard)
16C Albuterol (Proventil, Ventolin)
[...]
16Z DuoDote Auto-Injector
16AA Lidocaine Viscous Gel (Xylocaine ®)
16BB Lorazepam (Ativan)
16CC Magnesium Sulfate
```

Short of adding a `sort` column to my table, is there some way I can write a query to order these A-Z and then AA-ZZ, and so forth?

My thought: if I count where the space occurs in the `title`, I can order by that number ASC, then order by title ASC in second priority. This should give me all 3-digit codes first alphabetically, then all 4-digit codes alphabetically, then all 5-digit codes alphabetically, correct?

Comment: try `ORDER BY LEN(col), col`

Comment: Unfortunately the length of `title` is arbitrary because it is the code (like `16A`) followed by the actual title (which may have any length). But great thought!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, gee, I guess I just needed to talk through this. The solution was simple using MySQL `LOCATE()` to find the space and thus deduce the length of the code:

```
SELECT uid, file, title, 
LOCATE(' ', title) AS code_length 
FROM library 
WHERE section = '{$row['uid']}' AND enabled >0 
ORDER BY code_length ASC, title ASC
```

Comment: do you always have two digits for the numerical part, or it can change?

Comment: There are oftentimes one digit, BUT, they are always returned as a group. So all `16__` in one set, or all `1__` in one set, but never both intermingled.

Answer (score 3):

One way to use this is to get the first code using `substring_index()` and first sort by length and then the value:

```
order by length(substring_index(title, ' ', 1)),
         substring_index(title, ' ', 1)
```